# Can I run Adobe RoboHelp 20 on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows, server, adobe, robohelp

*Will Adobe RoboHelp 20 run on a Windows Server machine?*

We are currently looking to deploy 2 new copies of RoboHelp 20 on Windows VMs, to allow users RDP access to use the software.

Being a desktop application, ordinarily, we would deploy these onto Windows 10 Pro machines/VMs but we are currently low on Windows 10 Pro licenses and have Windows Server Core license packs to spare and would rather minimise cost in purchasing new licenses if at all possible.

I understand that RoboHelp do have a seperate server product that runs on Windows Server 2019 but from my understanding is a different product built on server to allow verison control and further collaboration and not neccesarily what we are looking for.

If not then we will of course have to look at purchasing more 10 Pro licenses, but thought I would test the water first just to see if anyone had run RoboHelp 20 on Windows Server before and if there were any issues?

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Answer (score 0):

Also interested.  I know it says you can't install on Windows Server, but not sure how you are supposed to provide that app when using Remote Desktop Services.  So it has to be able to install.  Maybe it only works inside RDS sessions (with desktop experience enabled?